# python recursive functions - troubled with output

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Having trouble with this python introductory course's last assignment.. first contact with programming, so..

Guidelines:

1. Implement the bother(n) function that returns a string containing "bother " (the word followed by a space) n times. If n is not a strictly positive integer, the function should return an empty string. This function must be implemented using **recursion**.
2. Using the above function, implement the elephants (n) function that returns a string containing the letter of "An elephant bothers a lot of people ..." from 1 to n elephants. If n is not greater than 1, the function should return an empty string. This function must also be implemented using **recursion**.

So, I tried:

```
def bother(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return ''
    elif n == 1:
        return 'bother '
    else:
        return 'bother ' + bother(n - 1)


def elephants(n):
    if n <= 0: return ''
    if n == 1: return 'An elephant bothers a lot of people...\r\n'
    return elephants(n - 1) \
           + str(n) + ' elephants ' + bother(n) + 'much more\r\n' \
           + str(n) + ' elephants ' + bother(n) + 'a lot of people\r\n'
```

But calling *elephants(2)* should return:

```
An elephant bothers a lot of people...
2 elephants bother much more
```

And calling *elephants(4)* should return:

```
An elephant bothers a lot of people...
2 elephants bother bother much more
2 elephants bother bother a lot of people
3 elephants bother bother bother much more
3 elephants bother bother bother a lot of people
4 elephants bother bother bother bother much more
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Use Visualise Python website if it's your first time with recursive functions, will make it a lot easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: I know where is the issue.. but I don't have the tools to fix it. I do use pythontuthor.com. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see much reasons to use recursive functions here.... why are you trying to do it that way?

Comment: It's an assignment.. can't do whatever I want to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def bother(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 'bother '
    elif n <= 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return 'bother ' + bother(n - 1)

def elephants(n, first=True):  #first keeps track of which output per n
    if n <= 0:
        return ''
    elif n == 1:
        return "An elephant bothers a lot of people"
    elif first:
        return elephants(n, not first) \
        + str(n) + ' elephants ' + bother(n - 1) + 'a lot of people' 
    else:
        return str(n) + ' elephants ' + bother(n - 1) + 'much more\n'


print(elephants(1))
print(elephants(2))
print(elephants(3))
print(elephants(4))


"""
This gives you the desired output. The main part of the elephants section if that it alternates between the two different returned strings:
-a lot of people         (first=True)
-much more               (first=False)

When called recursively it flips the Boolean with not operator and returns the second string, then flips back for the next value of n to the first returned string
"""
```

Comment: it isn't returning the right answer.. but I'll try fix it using this boolean trick. thx!